# in angular, how to get select/ ngModel previous value after change event fire

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working Angular 2 form and have drop-down/ select in template whose data is bind with ngModel and onChnage event. I need to detect previous value of ngModel? I have tried with data-* attributes 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp to store current value in it, hoping it won't change with ngModel value, followed by send back when event fire but getting NaN value when it pass on change.

drop-down / select initial values are mapped from array that is question[], current defaultValue is in "question.value"

### template

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'"> <small>dropdown</small>
           <div class="form-group">
                {{question.value}}
               <select [id]="question.key" 
                       [formControlName]="question.key" 
                       [(ngModel)]="question.value"  
                       data-default-element="question.value"     
                       (change)="onChangeValue($event, responseId, question.key, data-default-element , 'dropdown')" 
                       (blur)="onChangeValue($event, responseId, question.key, data-default-element , 'dropdown')"
                       >

                   <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" 
                           [value]="opt.key" >{{opt.value}} </option>
               </select>
           </div>            
       </div>
```

### component

```
onChangeValue(event: any, givenResponseId:string, givenQuestionId:string, defaultValue:string, givenInputType:string) { 

    var givenAnswer = null;

    console.log("defaultValue  ",defaultValue);

    if(event.target.value !="")
    {
       givenAnswer = event.target.value;
       console.log("newValue  ",givenAnswer );
    }

 }
```

Comment: I would advice not to use ngModel when you use reactive forms, unless you want to update something live maybe. Also, you pass `data-default-element` (not as a string) to your change method.Pass `question.value` instead, and remove ngModel, then you have previous /default value?

Comment: then my issue comes data binding that is coming from database initially and validation ????

Answer (score 2):

You must consider using OnChanges from '@angular/core'. With this you can get the current and the previous value. Here is an example. Notice that it only works on attribute of type Input

```
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-your-selector',
 templateUrl: './template-path.html',
 styleUrls: ['./style-path.css']
})
export class myComponent implements OnChanges{

 @Input() myAttribute : string;//This should be your ngModel attribute

 ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges ){
   if(changes["myAttribute"]){
    let currentValue = changes["myAttribute"].currentValue;
    let previousValue = changes["myAttribute"].previousValue;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: my form is generating dynamically, this may not fully applicable but i think i know what i can try next !... thanks .. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `ngModel` from your form, and pass `question.value` instead of `data-default-element` to your change method, you will get the previous value. Then, you can update `question.value` in your change-method to update it with the given answer if you want to. The `ngModel` will two-way bind the data, making your question.value being updated when the user enters something in the form.

Comment: then my issue comes data binding that is coming from database initially and validation ????

Comment: you must pass the value from your database as the state in your `FormControl`. e,g, `question.key =  new FormControl(stateFromDatabase,[]);` If you add the code from the controller where you create the FormGroup and FormController, maybe I can help out more

Comment: I have form group and I am binding data from array and calculating of its type, i.e. radio, text box, select

Comment: Can you add some code on how you build your form? I am guessing that my answer works, but now you are unable to bind the value from your database to your form, am I right?